# Angular set header and get div error x-frame-options sameorigin

Tags: angular, typescript, http, request

I am trying a `HttpClient` with `GET` and I am getting display error saying `X-Frame-Option` set to `sameorigin` while I am setting it to `ALLOWALL` throu header.
I am very new to `Angular`.
Any idea if I am doing this wrong or the server is blocking me trying to pop up them to my website?

```
constructor(http: HttpClient) 
  { 

    let authHeaders =  new HttpHeaders();
    authHeaders = authHeaders.set('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOWALL');
    //authHeaders.append('Accept-encoding', 'text/html');



    //let options = { headers: authHeaders };

    http.get<any>("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/TRIP/gIEqQYFW-TRIPADVISOR-long-term-buy-double-shares/", {headers:authHeaders});
  }
```

Comment: Is it angular or angularjs? Can't be both.

Comment: It is Angular 2+

Comment: This URL doesn't look like a REST API to me.

Comment: It is not an API